# Varying images at varying positions in Book and Memoir class chapter styles

Tags: graphics, memoir, chapters, positioning, books

I'm working on a chapter style: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/521832/leaf.noshadow.pdf) (pdf)

I want to use a different image at different positions in each chapter, sometimes even hanging into the title line (after the text), *but the title line should always stay at the same height on the page*.

How to define a chapter style that can be controlled this way? For both the **book** and the **memoir** documentclass.

(The book I'm working on is in **book** class, but I'd like to use this in some other projects which are in the memoir kingdom.)

Comment: I cannot say anything for the book class, haven't useed it for a long time. I think you need to be a bit more specific. How your would you control this? I would make the design without the image, and then add the image positioed globally on each chapter frontpage using the eso-pic package and the `\AddToShipoutPicture*` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up daleif's suggestion, using `\AddToShipoutPicture*` from the `eso-pic` package we don't need to tinker with the chapter styles at all:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./src-images/}}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello World}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
  % By default, eso-pic's zero coordinate is in the lower left corner
  \put(\LenToUnit{3.5in},\LenToUnit{5.5in}){%
    \includegraphics[height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{leaf.png}%
  }
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```